# Xamarin reusable xaml user control and custom command

Tags: xaml, xamarin, user-controls, icommand

first of all sorry for my english.
I am working on a iOS and Android project using Xamarin.Form

I would like to have a 'xaml user control' reusable in different way, and I need to make it clickable with ICommand

This is the StackLayoutButton component:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
 <StackLayout xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
x:Class="Installa.Controls.StackLayoutButton">
  <Image x:Name="Icon" Source="{Binding Icon}" />
  <Label x:Name="Text" Text="{Binding Title}" HorizontalOptions="Center" LineBreakMode="NoWrap" Font="Small" TextColor="Red" />
</StackLayout>
```

This is the CalendarioPage xaml page where the component is used

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:Installa.Controls;assembly=Installa"
             x:Class="Installa.CalendarioPage">

  <StackLayout>
    <Label Text="{Binding ViewName}" Font="42" IsVisible="{Binding IsWindowsPhone}" />
    <ActivityIndicator IsRunning="{Binding IsLoading}" IsVisible="{Binding IsLoading}" Color="Red" />

    <controls:StackLayoutButton BindingContext="{Binding Blog}" TextColor="Blue" /> <!-- Command="{Binding SubmitCommand}" --> 
    <controls:StackLayoutButton BindingContext="{Binding Facebook}" TextColor="Red" /> <!-- Command="{Binding SubmitCommand}" --> 
  </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

This is the CalendarioPage c# page:

```
public partial class CalendarioPage : ContentPage
{
    private CalendarioViewModel vm;

    public CalendarioPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        vm = new CalendarioViewModel();

        this.BindingContext = vm;
    }
 }
```

This is the viewmodel class:

```
namespace Installa
{
    public class CalendarioViewModel: BaseViewModel
    {

        public CalendarioViewModel()
        {
            blog = new Activity();
            blog.Link = "www.google.it";
            blog.Title = "Titolo del blog";
            blog.Icon = "logomenu.png";

            facebook = new Activity();
            facebook.Title = "Tito Fbook";
            facebook.Link = "www.facebook.it";
            facebook.Icon = "icon.png";

            ViewName = "nome della view";
            IsLoading = false;    
        }

        Activity blog = null;
        public Activity Blog
        {
            get {return blog;}
        }

        Activity facebook = null;
        public Activity Facebook
        {
            get { return facebook; }
        }

        string viewName = string.Empty;
        public string ViewName
        {
            get { return viewName; }
            set { SetProperty(ref viewName, value); }
        }

        public bool IsWindowsPhone
        {
            get
            {
                return Device.OS == TargetPlatform.WinPhone;
            }
        }

        bool isLoading = false;
        public bool IsLoading
        {
            get { return isLoading; }
            set { SetProperty(ref isLoading, value); }
        }           
    }
}
```

With Activity a simple class with:

```
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public string Link { get; set; }

    public String Icon { get; set; }
```

Till now, all is working right, but now I need to implement the ICommand interface.

In StackLayoutButton c# code I try to add:

```
        var tapGestureRecognizer = new TapGestureRecognizer();
        tapGestureRecognizer.SetBinding(TapGestureRecognizer.CommandProperty, "TapCommand");
        Icon.GestureRecognizers.Add(tapGestureRecognizer)
        Text.GestureRecognizers.Add(tapGestureRecognizer)
```

Furthermore I try to add into CalendarioViewModel INotifyPropertyChanged and the 'OnTapped' method.

Into Activity.cs i add 'ICommand tapCommand' and the related get...but is not working.

I try even other..but I am not able to enable the tap on the StackLayoutButton components.

In wich way I should do ? 
I'd like to be able to have a 'programmable' command...for example I would like browse to 'the link property' of Activity or be able to open a new view.

Thanks for help!

Update:

I was able to add TapGestureRecognizer into the xaml user control (StackLayoutButton.xaml.cs),
but I'd like to implement it in MVVM way,

```
using Xamarin.Forms;
namespace Installa.Controls
{
    public partial class StackLayoutButton : StackLayout
    {
        public StackLayoutButton()
        {
            InitializeComponent();


            TapGestureRecognizer tapGestureRecognizer = new TapGestureRecognizer
            {
                Command = new Command(OnMyComponentTapped),
                CommandParameter = "ciao"
            };
            this.Icon.GestureRecognizers.Add(tapGestureRecognizer);
            this.Text.GestureRecognizers.Add(tapGestureRecognizer);
        }


        async void OnMyComponentTapped(object parameter)
        {
            // do action
        }


        public Color TextColor
        {
            get { return this.Text.TextColor; }
            set { this.Text.TextColor = value; }
        }
        public Label TextControl
        {
            get { return this.Text; }
            set { this.Text = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

can anyone suggest me the way ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is how I add gesture recognizer on my xaml view:

```
<Label.GestureRecognizers>
    <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding SelectEquipmentCommand}"/>
</Label.GestureRecognizers>
```

And this is the ICommand property in my ViewModel:

```
    public ICommand SelectEquipmentCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return fSelectEquipmentCommand ?? (fSelectEquipmentCommand = new Command(async () => await SelectEquipmentTask()));
        }
    }

    private async Task SelectEquipmentTask()
    {

    }
```